# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS while initiating std::pair array

Tags: c++, arrays, std-pair

I am reading in network data from a .txt file to create a graph using Boost Graphs Library.

The format of the data is:

```
[num_nodes] [num_edges]
[source_node] [target_node]
[from_node] [to_node] [arc_weight_1] [arc_weight_2]
...
[from_node] [to_node] [arc_weight_1] [arc_weight_2]
```

For example,

```
264346 733846
229246 264275
1 2 803 2008
...
259707 261228 389 389
```

In the following code snippet, I am initialising an array of pairs to store the from/to node pair of each edge.

*Variables ending in an underscore are class member variables.*

```
std::ifstream infile("USA.txt");
infile >> num_nodes_ >> num_edges_ >> source_ >> target_;

std::pair<int, int> edge_pairs_array[num_edges_];
```

However, the last line gives me this error:

[image: Error message]

I can't figure out why. It can't be because 733846 elements is too large for an array.

As a sanity check, I wrote this in a separate file and it runs with no problems:

```
int main() {
    std::ifstream infile("USA.txt");
    int num_nodes, num_edges, source, target, u, v, x, y;
    infile >> num_nodes >> num_edges >> source >> target;
    std::pair<int, int> edge_pairs_array[num_edges];
    for (int i = 0; i < num_edges; i++) {
        infile >> u >> v >> x >> y;
        edge_pairs_array[i] = std::make_pair(u, v);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Could be. You're creating this array on the stack. You could use `std::vector` or put it on the heap.

Comment: As far as I know, Boost Graphs Library requires it to be an array. But more importantly, I'd just like to know the cause of the problem.

Comment: @kseulgi You're taking home the wrong point from that comment. It being an array is not the problem. It being on the stack probably is. Anyhow, `vector` lets you get the array via `.data()` even if that is the case and is safer/better practice than manually allocating.

Comment: @underscore_d Ahh, thanks for the clarification. I'll look into that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of `edge_pairs_array` is probably about 5.6 MB. It is an automatic variable, and is therefore allocated on what is called the "stack". The size of the stack varies between systems, but is usually one to few MB on desktop systems. What is most likely is that you've had a "stack overflow".

Solution is to allocate such large objects from the free-store. The simplest way to allocate an array from the free-store is to use `std::vector`.

The program is ill-formed in standard C++, since `num_edges_` is not a compile time constant. Only compile time constants can be used as the size of an automatic array.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'll try to follow your advice.